# How to obtain Camera Manufacturer/Make and Model from Android Device

Tags: android, makefile, model, camera, device

I utilize the following to find the Camera Manufacturer and Model from an image.

```
var exif = new ExifInterface(path);
cameraMfg = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagMake);
cameraModel = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagModel);
```

But I cannot obtain that information from a video.  I would like to grab the camera make and model from the Android Device.  I cannot seem to locate a library to do that.

I am not trying to get it from the image. I can do that. I know I cannot get it from the video. Therefore....I would like to get it from the Android device itself. Similar to windows and the ability to get the hardware device manufacturer and model. Any ideas?

Comment: [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface) only supports the following formats: JPEG, DNG, CR2, NEF, NRW, ARW, RW2, ORF, PEF, SRW and RAF.

Comment: In addition to only being in some formats, there's no promise that it will be present even in a supported formats.  Those fields are optional, and many apps do not fill it out for privacy reasons.

Comment: I am not trying to get it from the image.  I can do that.  I know I cannot get it from the video.  Therefore....I would like to get it from the Android device itself.  Similar to windows and the ability to get the hardware device manufacturer and model.  Any ideas?

Comment: Considering no answer, I guess it's not possible :(